# Getting started using java swing to draw

Tags: java, swing

I dont quite understand how to use java swing to draw something. I have:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

public MyFrame(){
    this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    this.pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(0, 250,500,250);

    panel.update(g);

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

This just gives me a empty frame. My thought process:

1. Make Frame.
2. Add "Canvas".
3. Get Graphics of "Canvas".
4. Draw something.
5. Update Graphics.

How can I draw lines and points properly and as simple as possible? For example to make graph theory algorithms or draw math graphs...
For me, all of the docs Ive seen so far just make new classes which override certain methods to draw lines, which is really confusing...
I want it to be like the online editor p5.js, but in java...

Comment: *I dont quite understand how to use java swing to draw something* - start with the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for step by step examples. Download the examples and play with them to practice simple painting. *I want it to be like the online editor* -  You need to learn the basics first before attempting something that complicated. The code posted here is the wrong structure for painting. You need to override the paintComponent(...) method of your custom painting panel.

Comment: For reusability sake, it is better to extend JPanel or anything other than JFrame or any of the window components (JWindow, JDialog).

Comment: An addendum to the advice of @ControlAltDel. The code above is setting a 500 x 500 size for the frame which means the `JPanel panel` will *not* be square. When extending the panel, override the `getPreferredSize` method to return a square dimension, then `pack()` the frame to fit around it.